# git status is not showing my changed files

Tags: node.js, git, github, node-modules

I have a Node.js project and have imported a few Node modules. The `git_status` command shows the files that I changed in the project. I have also changed some files under the `node_modules` directory but those are not shown. The `node_modules` directory is shown as untracked.

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

node_modules/
src/js/main-release-paths.json
```

I have changed only one file in `node_modules`:

```
node_modules/@oracle/grunt-oraclejet/node_modules/@oracle/oraclejet-tooling/lib/serve/connect.js
```

How can I track this file?

Comment: I really don't understand the question...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't add the `node_modules` folder to git then it's managed bei the `npm` command. So remove that folder and use the `npm install` command.

When you have added something in that folder it's shown as changed, if you had first added some files. So i hop that folder is in your `.gitignore` file and ignored. You should check that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have git repo, Please check the .gitignore files inside your project. Entries in .gitignore will be ignored by Git and will not show up when you do git add.

Comment: ... But the asker does see it in git status so it obviously is not ignored.

Answer (score 1):

### Adding the file to track

This is most likely not a suitable approach (read below). However , if you really want to do it:

In order to track a file nested under `node_modules`, you should `add` the directory. All of its content will be staged in git

```
git add node_modules
```

### Recommended approach

You probably don't want to track the contents of `node_modules` directory, because:

- running `npm install` will wipe your changes
- hundreds or thousand files are likely to end up present in that directory
- tracking `package.json`  and `package-lock.json` in git is sufficient, then populate node_modules using `npm install` command.

You are not supposed to modify files located in `node_modules` directory directly. Instead, fork the module in question, modify it, and:

- either publish your own version in npm
- or reference it as a git repository inside package.json ([how-to](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies))

Then, also add `node_modules` directory to the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole directory is untracked, `git status` will show only the directory. Because it's untracked, there is no meaningful difference to git between changed and unchanged files in there.

Other answers have already addressed that tracking `node_modules` is nota good idea. Of you want to track your changes to modules, consider cloning the module repo and including it as a  git submodule.

Answer (score 0):

It should be inside .gitignore file. A .gitignore file should be committed into your repository, in order to share the ignore rules with any other users that clone the repository.